# gsub consecutive characters and keep previous line

Tags: awk

I have this **input** file:

```
>seq
GATGGATTCGGANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGTTGTAGGGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```

And this **command**:

```
awk '{gsub(/[N]{5,}/,"\n")}1' f.fa
```

The current **output**:

```
>seq
GATGGATTCGGA
GTTGTAGGG
GATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```

If 5 or more consecutive 'N'-s are found, the string will be separated into another line. The problem is that I want the output to be like this:

```
>seq
GATGGATTCGGA
>seq_1
GTTGTAGGG
>seq_2
GATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```

Before each linebreak, I want to add the '>' line wich corresponds the string plus a increasing number (in order to be unique each '>' line). I've been trying different approaches but without success.

Comment: If it had to be repeated would the `suq` count start at 1 or 3 (where the `seq` count left off)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already done most of the work. Here are my additions:

```
 awk '$0~/^>/{prev=$0;}
      {gsub(/[N]{5,}/,"\n"prev"_INSERTNUMBER\n");
       for(counter=1;sub(/INSERTNUMBER/,counter++,$0)>0;){}}1' test
```

which yields the desired output

```
>seq
GATGGATTCGGA
>seq_1
GTTGTAGGG
>seq_2
GATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```

What have I added?
1. With `$0~/^>/{prev=$0;}` I store the content of the previous line that started with `>`.
2. Then, I replace `[N]{5,}` with `\n`prev`_INSERTNUMBER\n` (i.e., `\n>seq_INSERTNUMBER\n`)
3. Finally, we replace all `INSERTNUMBER`s with (1,2,...)

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS=">" 'NR>1{$0=RS $0; 
                      while(sub(/NNNNN+/, "\n" $1 "_" ++c "\n"));
                      printf "%s",$0}' file

>seq
GATGGATTCGGA
>seq_1
GTTGTAGGG
>seq_2
GATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```

Comment: Nice solution from you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ { key = $0; next }
{
    split($0,a,/N{5,}/)
    for (i=1; i in a; i++) {
        print key (i>1 ? "_"i-1 : "") ORS a[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
>seq
GATGGATTCGGA
>seq_1
GTTGTAGGG
>seq_2
GATAGAGAGNN
>suq
AAHAHAH
```